# How do I set my Models field to the selected value in my select box in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following editor-field with a select list inside:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <select name="listbox" id="listbox">
        @foreach (var item in Model.ExerciseName)
        {
            <option value="@item.Name">
                @item.Name
            </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

My model has a field ChosenExercise.
Is There an easy way to set Model.ChosenExercise to the selected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `option` with `selected="selected"` before your `foreach`

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <select name="listbox" id="listbox">

        <option value="@(Model.ChosenExercise)" selected="selected">@Model.ChosenExercise</option>

        @foreach (var item in Model.ExerciseName)
        {
            <option value="@item.Name">
                @item.Name
            </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```